# Connectedness of Metric Spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

I was looking at a proof of how if a metric space is disconnected then M contains a proper clopen set. The proof relied on the fact that M = A U B and A and B are disjoint open sets. It showed that A must be clopen and I couldn't help but notice that B must also be clopen in that case. So, would it be safe to say if M is disconnected, there must be at least two clopen sets?

Also, I was trying to understand if I could apply the concept of closeness to a disconnected subset (E) of M  and I just want to confirm that my reasoning for why it wouldn't work for a subset of M is because if the subset is E and E = E1 U E2 then E1 and E2 don't have to necessarily be open as the definition (given to me) just wants them to be disjoint and  for E1 and E2 to just subsets of open sets (A,B) and those disjoint open sets (A,B) might not be necessarily in E.

Comment: Yes, certainly. The complement of an open set is closed and the complement of a closed set is open, so the complement of a clopen set is clopen.  But the word "clopen" is weird, so it's standard to say connectedness is about the space being a disjoint union of two nonempty open sets.  By the way, if $E = E_1 \cup E_2$, then $E_1$ and $E_2$ *are* in $E$.

Comment: "The proof relied on the fact that M = A U B and A and B are disjoint open sets." you must add that they are non-empty. You are right, they are both proper and clopen.

Comment: It is not clear 1) *what* you are "trying to apply to a subset" $E$ of $M$ 2) where your $E_1,E_2$ come from 3)  if you assume that $E$ is disconnected.

Comment: @KCd thank you! I think I meant that E1 and E2 are subsets of open disjoint sets A and B and I was just wondering if they don't have to be in E and can have elements that are in the complement.